# Symmetric matrics have pivots with the same signs as their eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

How would I prove the title statement? My Gilbert Strang Ed. 5 Linear Algebra textbook talks about $LDL^T$ factorization but I don't quite understand it. Online proofs also talk about Sylvester's Law of Inertia - but I can't find any good definitions of it. I've also attempted to try and work out the algebraic expressions for pivots of a symmetric matrix - however at dimensions beyond $3 \times 3$ the operations become far too tedious to complete, however this method did work for $3 \times 3$ matrices and ones of lower dimensions. Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I could write you Sylvester's theorem

Comment: That would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Let $\varphi$ be a bilinear $\textbf{symmetric}$ form such that $rk(\varphi)=r$ and $V$ a  real vector space whose dimension is $n$. Then it will exist an integer $0\le p\le r$, uniquely determined by $\varphi$, and a basis $\mathcal B=\{e_1,e_2,\dots, e_n\}$ of $V$ such that $$M_{\mathcal B}(\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}I_p&&0&&o\\0&&-I_{r-p}&&0\\0&&0&&0_{n-r} \end{pmatrix}.$$ Remember that the segnature of a matrix $A$ is denoted with $sgn(A)=(k,l)$, where $k$ is the numeber of positive eigenvalues and $l$ is the number of negative eigenvalues.